# Sorry, firefox.exe/chrome.exe is taking a while to load | (unresponsive) firefox.exe/chrome.exe

Tags: chromium, oculus, webvr, htc-vive, firefox-nightly

I'm making an application with WebVR using React VR. I'll test the application with my Oculus Rift and HTC-Vive. I'm using the browser Firefox Nightly to access the WebVR API's.

If I browse to my application using Firefox Nightly or Chromium, I arrive in an empty space with a loading message. A few seconds later I got this message on my Oculus Rift:

> Sorry, *firefox.exe/chrome.exe* is taking a while to load. If this issue persists, please take off your headset and check this app on your computer.

On the HTC-Vive I got this message in Steam VR but it doesn't load at all.

> (unresponsive) *firefox.exe/chrome.exe*

In the webbrouwser, I got the result I must see inside the headset with motion tracking.

I'm using this browsers

- **Version Firefox nightly:** 55.0a1
- **Version Chromium:** 56.0.2910.0

And this are my specifications:

- **GeForce:** GTX 970
- **GeForce Game Ready Driver:** 378.66
- **Processor:** Intel<sup>®</sup> Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- **RAM:** 15.87 GB

Comment: I have the same issue, wish I could help :/

Comment: I was able to get things working by rolling back Oculus to version 1.12 AND rolling back NVidia drivers to a version from Feb'17. I'm doing some more experiments now to determine whether the Oculus rollback was really needed. Once I have a clear answer, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the Oculus software at all. The problem is an NVIDIA driver update that broke everything. You need to go to the NVIDIA site and download drivers from the "376" generation (Dec'16-Feb'17). Install those and the problems go away. I confirmed that things are working with Oculus 1.12, 1.14, and 1.14 beta channel.

It *looked* like Oculus broke things because 1.14 came out on almost the same day as the "381" NVidia driver update.

Comment: I've downgraded the nvidia drivers to 376.53 but didn't help the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading my Nvidia driver to 376 worked as a charm for me, but I can't run the VR scenes on Nightly, just on Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my Oculus to work with WebVR by enabling the Beta channel within the oculus app and letting it install an update. Seems like the current Oculus version might be broken.

Comment: I'm afraid that your answer doesn't work for me. I've reinstalled the Oculus setup and joined the beta test channel, but still have the same problem. Could you give me more information?

Comment: I didn't reinstall Oculus, just relaunched it and it downloaded the update in the background. Chrome is still broken for me, but Firefox is working ‍♀️

Comment: Tried this, and neither Chrome nor Firefox are working for me.

Comment: Not directly related to Oculus but _may_ still be relevant. NVidia drivers after 378.92 broke ChromeVR/Vive, but driver 384.94 got it working again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try installing SteamVR. SteamVR overrides the Oculus runtime and runs applications on its own.
2. Try closing Oculus Home before you launch your WebVR application using the WebVR button.
3. Make sure you are not in the Beta/Dash mode in Oculus
4. Try to disable the auto-opening of Oculus Home. Oculus home opens automatically on wearing the rift. To disable, select “Run as admin” field in the properties of the Oculus app. More specifically, go to /Oculus-Directory/Support/oculus-client/OculusClient, right click, select properties, check “Run as Administrator”.
5. Make sure that your Desktop and Rift are connected to the same Graphic card. You might need an HDMI to DVI converter for the same. This is what fixed the problem for me.